# How can I cycle through images in javascript to do some image processing?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to cycle through a list of images.
For each image, I'm trying to display it on a canvas, and to extract some information from it - in this example, it is as simple as it's width. The problem is that only the last image is displayed, and the values for the width are always undefined.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>

<canvas id="canvas" width="100" height="100"></canvas>
<script>
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var paths = ['images/people/img_1.jpg', 'images/people/img_2.jpg', 'images/people/img_3.jpg'];
    var width = new Array(3);

    processImages();

    function processImages() {

        function display(img, i) {
            canvas.width = img.width;
            canvas.height = img.height;
            ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
            width[i] = img.width;
            alert("i = " + i);
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            var img = new Image();

            img.onload = (function (x) {
                return function() {
                    display(this, x);
                }
            })(i);

            img.src = paths[i];
        }

        for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            document.write("<br>Image " + i + " width is: " + width[i]);
        }
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

`image.onload` is called asynchronously -- when the image loads, it fires an event that will execute that function. So the `for` loops will execute before `onload` functions are even called, and `width` will not contain anything when you are trying to write to the document.

So let's say I had this code:

```
var width = {};
for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    setTimeout(function(){
       width[i] = i * 2;
    }, 0);
}

for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    console.log(width[i]);
}
```

You would get `undefined` outputted every time since the timeout functions did not execute.

You see the last image after the code runs because you write to the same position in the canvas every time. You may want to either delay writing to the canvas or position the images somewhere else so they don't overlap, depending on what you intend on doing.

Answer (score 0):

If you append the image to the HTML you can get width and height.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>

<canvas id="canvas" width="100" height="100"></canvas>
<script>
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var paths = ['head.png', 'body.png', 'car.png'];
    var width = new Array(3);
    var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];

    // save number of images loaded
    var totalLoaded = 0;

    processImages();

    function processImages() {

        function display(img, i) {
            canvas.width = img.clientWidth;
            canvas.height = img.clientHeight;
            ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
            width[i] = img.clientWidth > 100;
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            var img = new Image();

            img.onload = (function (x) {


                return function() {
                    // append to the html
                    body.appendChild(this);

                    //  now you have the width available
                    console.log(this.clientWidth);

                    // do whatever you need
                    display(this, x);

                    // remove the image
                    body.removeChild(this);

                    // check if all of the images were loaded
                    totalLoaded++
                    if(totalLoaded >= paths.length) {
                        onComplete();
                    }
                }
            })(i);

            img.src = paths[i];
        }

        function onComplete () {
            for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                document.write("<br>Image " + i + " width is: " + width[i]);
            }
        }
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

document.write is very, very old school and there are only really a couple of very specialised cases where it should be used. Try something like this instead:

```
<body>

<canvas id="canvas" width="100" height="100"></canvas>
<div id="w"></div>
<script>
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var paths = ['images/people/img_1.jpg', 'images/people/img_2.jpg', 'images/people/img_3.jpg'];
    //var width = new Array(3);

    processImages();

    function processImages() {

        function display(img, i) {
            canvas.width = img.width;
            canvas.height = img.height;
            ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
            document.getElementById("w").innerHTML+="<br>Image " + i + " width is: " + img.width;
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            var img = new Image();

            img.onload = (function (x) {
                return function() {
                    display(this, x);
                }
            })(i);

            img.src = paths[i];
        }

    }
</script>

</body>
```